# How to restrict SQL Server from accepting empty string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server which has a constraint like `Not null`. When I enter new entry if I am not filling anything, SQL Server pops error message preventing `Null` value.

But once I enter one record and later if I edit that record by just deleting the data in this column, SQL Server is accepting the empty string.

Comment: Program logic should handle this, don't allow your program to delete/remove the value and replace with empty if that is not desired.

Comment: Your description does not sound correct.  If the column has a `NOT NULL` constraint, then it is not allowed in the column.  Perhaps the value is an empty string `''` rather than `NULL`.

Comment: Optionally investigate Check constraints. CHECK constraints determine the valid values from a logical expression that is not based on data in another column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [CHECK CONSTRAINT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
ALTER TABLE table
ADD CONSTRAINT chkNotEmpty CHECK (LEN(col) > 0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

By UI you can add constraint by following step

- 1.open the table in Design view

  2. Right Click any column and select "Check Constraints"
  3. Edit"Expression"  and set the minimum lenth of any field as
     **len(desiredField)>=1**